# "If fi" within a "case esac"

Tags: bash, if-statement, case

I tried to use the code below :

```
read choice
case $choice in 
"1")    less /var/log/messages
    if [$? -ne 0]; then 
        less /var/log/syslog
    fi
    ;;
etc
etc
etc
*) echo "Please enter a choice between 1 and 20";;
esac
```

when executing ./myScript.sh I got this :

```
./myScript.sh: line 4: [1: command not found
```

I can't find the problem !

Comment: You need to separate `[` and `$?` as well as `0` and `]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your `if` statement, put space after `[` and before `]`, as

```
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
```

Comment: Thanks @Rohan . It was the space like you said.

Answer (score 1):

At (4, 8) and (4, 16) are the problems. Place a space between (4, 7) and (4, 8) and another space between (4, 15) and (4, 16). These ordered pairs are like (line, column).

Do it like this on line 4:

```sh
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
```